# Pass a property from one controller to other on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am working an a Azure Mobile Service on iOS and i have enabled authentication. I expanded the default app that microsoft gives as an example to use a tabBarController. One controller is the default that MS uses and is called ToDoListController.

I want to use the todoService property that is used in ToDoListController in my second controller that is AddItemController. So, in the header of ToDoListController i have

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) TodoService *todoService;
```

and in the m of the same controller i have the synthesize of it.

When i want to use this property in tabBarController, i refer to it as

```
(((TodoListController *)self.parentViewController).todoService)
```

but i get

> [UITabBarController todoService]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

and

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController todoService]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: The problem is that self.parentViewController is a UITabBarController, not a ToDoListController

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to access one of your tab bar controllers. Try this

```
for (UIViewController *v in ((UITabBarController*)self.parentviewController).viewControllers)
{
     UIViewController *vc = v;

     if ([v isKindOfClass:[TodoListController class])
     {
         ((TodoListController *)v).todoservice;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the .h file of the ToDoService into your tabBarController?  That will allow visibility to the tabBarController. Apologies in advance for not using the comment feature, I'm not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you sending selector to a wrong controller, try to detect which one in you hierarchy exactly yours TodoListController. Why do you think that parentViewController is TodoListController?

if you are presenting as modal current VC inside UITabBarController then parentVC is UITabBarController.

also you can try `self.parentViewController.parentViewController`;

Comment: I don't know if parentViewController is TodoListController, i  tried this as a technique from a book. How can i see the hierarchy to access the right property? self.parentViewController.parentViewController doesn't works...

Comment: Can you explain more detailed your app screens order? How do you get into current view controller (which code is in your sample).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making your TodoService a singleton. There are many ways to do this, here's a simple piece of code that creates a singleton you can access anywhere*. Add this method signature to your TodoService.h file

```
+ (TodoService *) defaultService;
```

And this implementation

```
TodoService *todoService;

+ (TodoService *)defaultService
{
    if (todoService == nil) {
        todoService = [[TodoService alloc] init];
    }
    return todoService;
}
```

Now from anywhere in your application, you can access the single instance via

```
TodoService* service = [TodoService defaultService];
[service doSomething];
```

*Note, there are better ways of implementing a singleton in Objective C, but this is a fine method in most cases where you only call defaultService on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was a breakpoint. Data passing nice now, without problems through

```
(((TodoListController *)self.parentViewController).todoService)
```